# Is there a linux fs kernel driver for NTFS R/W and how does it compare to the fuse solution?

Tags: filesystems, kernel-modules, ntfs

Is there an out of tree linux kernel NTFS kernel driver that provides R/W capabilities?

I know there's fuse+NTFS-3G, but I've had it consume way too many CPU cycles.

My question is: is there a (preferably free) out-of-tree linux kernel fs driver for NTFS, and if so, does it perform a lot better or is it just not worth the effort?

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is [the paragon driver](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-per/).

The driver is significantly faster than ntfs-3g but it's not OpenSource.
If you need it for a specific application where you can't work around it, it's definitely worth investigating.

Comment: Update: Paragon is integrating its driver into the kernel directly https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/?q=ntfs3 .

Answer (score 2):

Paragon ships a [Free version](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-linux-professional/#comparison) with few limits available [at this link](http://dl.paragon-software.com/free/Paragon-715-FRE_NTFS_Linux_9.5_Express.tar.gz).

Unfortunately it supports kernels only up to the 4.12.

The performances of Paragon driver over NTFS-3G are not comparable: Paragon is absolutely the winner!

Answer (score 1):

[NTFS-defused](https://github.com/gzg1984/NTFS-defused) also exists, as an attempt to update the in-tree driver.

AFAICT it should at least be capable of creating and deleting files and folders, but I'm not sure about anything else (including its reliability).

EDIT: Paragon's full and complete driver is [getting FOSS](https://www.theregister.com/2020/09/08/paragon_ntfs_linux/)